# Data ageing and concept drift

Tags: dataset, terminology, concept-drift

I have a simple question. 
In the literature I am reading "data ageing" and "concept drift" are mentioned, and I just want to make sure that I understand the difference between the two terms. The context is in data-driven modelling.

If I understand things correctly data ageing would apply when a model is trained on data that is old, and thus not representative of the phenomenon any more. The model should not be able to accurately predict the target variable when it is trained.

With concept drift on the other hand the model can be trained with up to date data and perform well at the time of training. As time passes however changes occur which causes performance to decrease.

Basically my question is; Is this right?

Comment: Your description doesn't raise any red flags for me. One point worth remembering is that the two terms aren't orthogonal or mutually exclusive. There is a high degree of overlap in their meaning and usage. One way to operationalize them is by fixing the parameters on an initial set of data and then comparing any ageing, drift or change on new data based on two sets of metrics for accuracy and dependence, then and now.

Comment: Those are good comments as well
Thanks.